# MySQL new joined query taking too long with subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out exactly why my query is taking so long. It's usually taking around 60 - 90 seconds per query, and it is executed several times.

The old query:

```
     "select * from $table where type = '".$type."' and transdate >= '".$begdate."' and 
      transdate<='".$enddate."' and customerin (select customer from master
      where targetaccount='Y') ";
```

New Query:

```
    $q = "SELECT * FROM activity  INNER JOIN custactivities ON 
    activity.activityID = custactivities.activityID  WHERE  type  = '$type'  AND  
    transdate BETWEEN '$begdate' AND '$enddate'  AND  custnum  IN 
    (SELECT customer FROM master WHERE targetaccount = 'Y')  
    GROUP BY custactivities.customer";
```

The original query takes around 0.15 seconds and the new query takes around 60-90 seconds per query.

This does have some PHP in it, but the query is none the less the issue.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Print the resulting query, we don't need to see your PHP. Also, you can find out if your query uses index appropriately by using explain, learn to debug your code and queries, we can't help without your database structure.

Comment: Why are you using `group by` with no aggregation functions and `select *`?

Comment: @DanyCaissy I took out majority of the PHP. It still needs to be in there so that it is reminded that it is a variable. Also there is a key in custactivities however, none of them I can use because there is one field that is very specific and I can't acquire that data.

@GordonLinoff Yes, `Select *` I could replace that honestly. but I doubt thats causing a huge time difference. No aggregation because none of the functions matches what I need. If anything I would just replace the `select *`.

Would you like me to post the `show create table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add indexes to the following columns, if you don't have

```
activityID on both table
type - if it's numeric, don't use the '
transdate
targetaccount - if you can, use numeric, or enum definition for that column for better indexing
```

And if your master table is not too big with the where targetaccount = 'Y', you can separate it to another query, fetch with php and insert the array to your query with implode, instead of using a subquery.

And never use the * , as ChrisS mentioned.

Here is a little code snippet with php and mysql

```
$cust = array();
$sql = 'SELECT customer FROM master WHERE targetaccount = "Y"';
$query = mysql_query();
if ($query) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
        $cust[] = $row[0]
    }
}

$sql = "select * from $table where type = '".$type."' and transdate >= '".$begdate."' and 
      transdate<='".$enddate."'" . (count($cust) ? ' AND custnum IN ('.implode(', ', $cust).')' : '');
```

I haven't tested, but I think now you see the point.

Comment: I tried separating the master into another query and it failed to provide the correct information. It also throws an error at times, when the query will return no results. (I know the error should be handled on my part, just so ya know)

I agree on the `targetaccount` being numeric, however, I didn't design this database. I'm picking up scraps. 

Also, what make `select *` such a bad thing? I've read that its supposedly slows down queries, but I've never seen a sign of that happening.

Comment: It's slows down the query, yes. If you have only a few visitors with a few queries per sec, it's not much, but if you have million visitors with millions of query, it takes too much time

Comment: that is definitely noted then. I appreciate that bit of info.

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated ^_~. I wasn't thinking of doing that if statement for the query. Eh, my brain is like dead from trying to figure this issue out.

Comment: Yes, mysql is deprecated from PHP 5.5, but from the code snippet you can easily rewrite to anything else, this is just a sample.

Answer (score 1):

Can you JOIN to 'master'? That would speed things up quite a bit I think. You slowdown is most likely that sub-select. Also, just for that sake of memory management, you may not want to do a 'SELECT *' but rather a 'SELECT col1, col2' for only the columns you need.

Comment: Although joining the `master` table works and massivly improves the time on the query, what makes the new query slow down without the join to `master`?

Comment: You were comparing each row to the list the sub query returns. When you JOIN you compile a list first then narrow it down with the WHERE. Basically, your query was going out and grabbing all the rows without being filtered on master then checking each row to the list master was returning.